# Typescript - Has no index signature when use Enums as index signature types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the follow type structure:

```js
export type Method1 = (id: string, param: string) => Promise<any>

export enum ValuesList {
  VALUE1 = 'VALUE1',
  VALUE2 = 'VALUE2'
}

export type ValuesMap = {
  [key in ValuesList]: {
    callMethod: Method1
  }
}

export const methodsMap: ValuesMap = {
  [ValuesList.VALUE1]: {
    callMethod: lib.method
  },
  [ValuesList.VALUE2]: {
    callMethod: lib2.method
  }
}
```

And in some part of the application I want to map some list to call this method dynamically:

```
methodsMap[target].callMethod(data.id, data.param)
```

By typescript are returning the follow problem:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ValuesMap' has no index signature.ts(7017)
```

Typescript are not recognise `ValuesMap` as an element with a index. If I change the `ValuesMap` to use `[key: string]` instead of `[key in ValuesList]` it works, but I would like to keep the `[key in ValuesList]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's recap some terminology. In TypeScript, index signature can be either a string or a number, but nothing narrower. If you, instead of using just the `string` type, explicitly specify the type via a literal, that's called a property, not an index signature. That's why enums never have a type signature but do have properties.

```js
type A = {
   [key: string]: number // this is index signature
};

type B = {
   [key in 'foo' | 'bar']: number // this is a property 
}
```

Now to the actual code. The snippet you posted seems to be working just fine. When you leave your mouse over the name `ValuesMap`, a tooltip will show you that it is:

```
type ValuesMap = { VALUE1: { callMethod: Method1; }; VALUE2: { callMethod: Method1; }; }
```

So, indeed, it contains the two values from the Enum. The problem therefore has to be the `target` you're using as an index. Because TypeScript is complaining about seeing no index signature, my best guess is that the `target` you're using is of type `string`, therefore possibly not a value of that enum. (You can hover your mouse above it to see its type.) Since TypeScript wants to protect you from calling the `callMethod` on undefined, it starts yelling at you until you restrict `target` to the correct values.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the problem is the target. But how can I fix it? I'm using a map function to call the method `targets.map((target: string) => { methodsMap[target].callMethod(data.id, data.param) })`, I tried use `(target: typeof ValuesList)` instead, but then return `Type 'typeof ValuesList' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)`

Comment: The type of your `target` has to be the enum. If your enum is called `Foo`, then `targets` has to be `Foo[]`. You can leave out the type in the arrow function, TypeScript will automatically recognize it.

Comment: Here's an example of how it can work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-biqdvf

Comment: Thanks! Its works. Actually, I was using Ramda to map the targets object, so I also need to type the target object with the enum like `R.map((target: ValuesList)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but if you want to make an arrow function return the type you want, you can use either return type inference (`let arr: myType[] = foo.map(...)`), or type assertion directly at the parameter (`map( x => y(x) as myType`). However it seems to be out of the scope of this question, so if you still struggle, feel free to open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your `enum` as a variable to check values against:

If you have

```
export enum ValuesList {
  VALUE1 = 'VALUE1',
  VALUE2 = 'VALUE2'
}
```

Then use:

```
someVariable: { [key: string]: ValuesList } = ValuesList
```

Instead of:

```
someVariable: ValuesList = ValuesList
```